# 'ignite' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: react-native, ignite

I recently discovered Ignite and followed the guide from here: https://github.com/infinitered/ignite to install it. I get a few warnings on install but nothing serious:

```
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
C:\Users\adrians\AppData\Roaming\npm\ignite -> C:\Users\adrians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-ignite\index.js
```

and:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\adrians\AppData\Roaming\package.json'
npm WARN adrians No description
npm WARN adrians No repository field.
npm WARN adrians No README data
npm WARN adrians No license field.
```

Then, when trying to run:

```
ignite new MyApplication
```

I get the following error message:

```
'ignite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I use Windows 10 by the way. Any ideea what to do next? 
I already tried adding a system variable for the ignite folder but no luck so far.

Comment: what node version you are using ?

Comment: Have you installed yeoman `npm install -g yo`

Answer (score 2):

Try to `npm install -g react-native-ignite` it worked from me.

Answer (score 0):

win + x

Click the System link.

Type Environment Variables.. in Find a Setting input

Click Environment Variables. ...

Under the System Variables locate Path and choose EDIT

*Before you go and edit, copy this entire string and paste it into Notepad. In case something goes wrong, you can paste it back.*

Add Path to iginte in this Variable
Usually it is located in "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin"

Note:USER_NAME is your User name in windows.

Comment: The problem is ignite is not recognizable as internal command, not yarn. The solution above is for yarn not for ignite. And voted down.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the Yarn Environment Variable worked for me and should work assuming you installed Ignite with Yarn and didn't already have it set up.

Search Env in the start bar search, "Edit the system environment variables" should show up.

Click Environment Variables, then under the System heading press Edit with the Path variable highlighted and add a New entry for C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin

Answer (score 0):

To use ignite on windows please follow the below:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native-ignite
npm install --global yo

ignite new MyNewApp
cd MyNewApp
react-native run-android
```